# GRASS: populating attribute table with specific values

Tags: grass-gis, vector

I have a vector map that includes 100 points.  These points were created using `v.extract` to randomly sample a larger map of 10k points.  As such, the 'cat' values range from 1 to more than 10k.  What I would like to do is to update the attribute table by rescaling these values to 1 to 100.

Here's what I've experienced.  If I use

```
v.category input=pts100 output=foo option=del
v.category input=foo output=pts100 option=add --o
```

Then when the 'cat' values *appear* rescaled when I print them with

```
v.category input=pts100 option=print
```

However, if I look at the dbtable with

```
db.select pts100
```

the 'cat' values have not changed (presumably because it is the key column).

So I'm thinking I will need to add a new column using `v.db.addcol`, but I don't know how to specify the range of value to populate the new column.  From what I can tell, I have to specify a single value.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new column in which you will populate the new record values

```
v.db.addcol map=pts100 columns="newcol int"
```

Initialize the value variable that you will use to update the record.

```
val=1
```

Run a loop based on existing cat values that will update records incrementally

```
for i in `v.category pts100 option=print`; do
   v.db.update pts100 column=newcol value=$val where="cat=$i"
   val=$val+1
done
```

This results in a new column of values that are scaled 1-100

Answer (score 0):

If you use the dbf driver you can carefully use LibreOffice (or Open Office) to edit directly the dbf file... just be careful not to add/remove records.